# Bold text in newenvironment

Tags: environments

I want to define my own environment, like

```
\newenvironment{question}
{\begin{tiny}}
{\end{tiny}}
```

That may not make much sense, but it works. How can I do the same with bold font?

Comment: There is no environment `tiny`. There is a command `\tiny`. The same can be achieved with `\bfseries`: `\newenvironment{foo}{\bfseries}{}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a "switch", achieved by issuing `\bfseries` at the start of the environment (say `boldenv`):

```
\newenvironment{boldenv}
  {\bfseries}% \begin{boldenv}
  {}% \end{boldenv}
```

The scope of this switch is limited to the environment, since `\begin{boldenv}` ... `\end{boldenv}` naturally forms a group. Also, *italicized* text inside this environment will inherit the **bold** switch (for example, if you use `\textit{<stuff>}`). To avoid this, you'd have to restore the font using something like `{\normalfont\itshape <stuff>}`.

Answer (score 7):

There is no environment `tiny`. There is a command `\tiny`. The same can be achieved with `\bfseries`: `\newenvironment{foo}{\bfseries}{}` –

---

I think it's important to mention a fact which is mostly unknown: *Don't use font commands as environments.*

**Explanation:**

Let me start with a small example and the unwanted output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}\tiny\blindtext\end{quote}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}\begin{tiny}\blindtext\end{tiny}\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

**What happened**

First you can see the different line spacing. In the first example (the correct one) `\begin{quote}\tiny\blindtext\end{quote}` the command `\par` is executed with the font size `\tiny`. So the space is correct. In the second example `\begin{quote}\begin{tiny}\blindtext\end{tiny}\end{quote}` the inner environment makes a local switch to `\tiny` and the closing `\par` by `quote` uses the default font size. So the complete paragraph is getting the wrong spacing.